# Is it correct to use 'folks' in the same sense as 'people' in general?

Tags: word-usage, vocabulary

I want to know if these sentences are not weird:

> - Democracy is government of, by and for the **folks**.
> - Within minutes of the event, **folks** were tweeting about it.
> - Many cafés and other public places now offer **folks** a wi-fi connection to the Internet.

In my view as a new English learner, the sentences I wrote up there are all weird (I can't tell the reason, I just sense it is). I'm intending to increase my vocabulary by studying all possible synonyms of a word that I can use exactly the same as the original word.

By the way, if you ask me where I got those sentences, I picked those words from my vocabulary exercise book,and just substituted the word *people* with *folks* (plural).

Comment: I wouldn't call them [weird](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/weird) , but the last two sound informal and the first one is a bit odd because _folks_ is not the kind of word that would normally be found in an official definition.

Comment: Where it isn't in a regional vernacular, _folks_ suggests a homeliness or a cosiness which is out of place in your first sentence and ingratiating in the others. The word _people_ is neutral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Folks" is informal, and often suggests a casual, southern style homeliness or a cosiness (also mentioned in the comments).

> Democracy is government of, by and for the folks.

That's comical, and doesn't precisely make sense. While "the people" here refers to all people in general, "the folks" (using the *definite* article) usually refers to specific people, the same way "the TV" refers to a specific TV.

You could change "the folks" to simply "folks" and say "Democracy is government for folks who enjoy votin'".

> Within minutes of the event, folks were tweeting about it.

> Many cafés and other public places now offer folks a wi-fi connection to the Internet.

All of the above sentences are more "spoken English" than "written English", and sound like a cowboy in the wild west, or someone with a rural accent who is being ingratiating.